Tableau Custom Color Palette Automatic Default
I made a custom color palette and have no issue doing that but when I assign it to a measure type (one that changes based on filtering, so I can't assign specific values to specific colors), and change a filter it resets to the old color palette. Is there a way to make it so that the color palette never changes, or always uses the custom color palette? Thank you!
I tried removing the name in the XML, I saw someone say this would work but it did not.

You can make a calculated field to bucket or group your measures by a specified range or ranges. Something like:
IF [measure] <= 5 THEN 'low'
ELSEIF [measure] <= 10 THEN 'med'
ELSE 'high'
END

Then drag this to the color tab in your marks pane. From here, assign the colors as you wish. Now you can filter using your original measure and the colors should change on the sheet when the measure value falls within one of your specified ranges.
Add this calculated field to other sheets' color tab in their marks pane, if those sheets are using the same [measure], it should "default" or automatically use your same color to variable selections.
